# Slow cooker cooked too fast

Tags: slow-cooking

Supposed to cook a 3 lb. pork loin on low 6-8 hrs., (was on low), to an internal temp of 160. Meat reached temp at 2 hours. What to do so it can be served in 4 more hrs. without being overdone or dried out?

Answer (score 4):

Pork loin is very lean and tender, so it's a bad cut for a slow cooker. Slow cookers work best with fatty or collagen-rich cuts that should be held at a high temperature for long enough for the connective tissue to "melt" and create a super rich, tender result. Pork loin will simply dry out. I would remove it from the cooker and chill until dinner. Either reheat gently or serve cold tonight. In the future, be wary of recipes that involve lean, tender cuts in a slow cooker.

Comment: To reheat, I would recommend hearing up the liquid, then slicing up the pork and putting that in the liquid to warm up.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the lid on and make sure there is liquid in the pot so it doesn't dry out. The idea of slow cooking isn't that food will only reach temperature at the end of the allocated time, it is that the extended time changes the texture of the meat and allows flavours to develop and blend further.